Delete rows of text between two values with Python
I've got a requirement to run a python script that will remove blocks/rows of text between two predictable comment blocks.
Let's say I have a file like this:
## Start of Part 1
Some text
Some more text
A bit more text
## End of Part 1

## Start of Part 2
Some text again
Some more text again
A bit more text again
## End of Part 2

I want to delete all the rows between ## Start of Part 1 and ## End of Part 1, including the comment lines
Is there a way with Python to do that?

Pass filename in the command line:
import sys
f = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
skip = False
for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line == '## Start of Part 1':
        skip = True
    if not skip:
        print(line)
    if line == '## End of Part 1':
        skip = False

